# how to say: 'I didn't go either'

Tags: traduction

I want to express: "I didn't go either"

My suggestion: "Je ne suis ni aller"
However, I only know "ni" in conjunction with a listing of different options/things, so I'm not sure whether this is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct translation would be :
"Je n'y suis pas allé non plus"

You could also say "Je n'y suis également pas allé", which would be slighltly different but would express the same meaning (like "I also didn't go")